# Find nth largest number infinite loop C++

Tags: c++, loops, quicksort

I have a vector of N numbers and I want to find the nth number in the array. I'm using a variation of the quicksort but I'm getting an issue with infinite loops at times and I think it's if the largest number is the only option in the two arrays. A number can appear many times in the array so if, for example I select 10 for N and I want to find 1st largest number I might end up with {9,9} in the left array leading to an infinite loop. What can I do to remedy this? Here is my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
int partition(int n, int arrsize, vector<int> intarr); //pass vector by val

int main() {

    int n, N;

    cout << "Please enter n: " << endl;
    cin >> n;
    cout << "Please enter N: " << endl;
    cin >> N;

    vector<int> array;
    srand(time(NULL));

    for(i=0; i < N; i++) {
        array.push_back(1 + rand() % N);
        cout << array.at(i) << ", ";
    }

    //Get the nth largest value of array[N]
    int arraylen = array.size();
    cout << "\nArraylen is " <<  arraylen << endl;
    int result = partition(n, arraylen, array);

    cout << "The " << n << "th largest number is: " << result <<endl;

    return 0;
}

int partition(int n, int arrsize, vector<int> intarr) {
    //1. Get a random value from the array:
        int random = rand() % arrsize;
        int pivot = intarr.at(random);

    //2. Partition the array into 2 halves left < pivot > right
        vector<int> left;
        vector<int> right;

        for(int j=0; j < arrsize; j++) {
            if (intarr[j] >= pivot)
                left.push_back(intarr[j]);
            else if (intarr.at(j) < pivot)
                right.push_back(intarr[j]);
            else continue;
        }

        cout << "\n \n" << "Left = ";

        for(int k = 0; k < left.size(); k++) {
            cout << left.at(k) << ", ";
        }

        cout << endl << "Right = ";

        for(int k = 0; k < right.size(); k++) {
            cout << right.at(k) << ", ";
        }

        int leftlen = left.size();
        int rightlen = right.size();

        if (n < leftlen)
            return partition(n, leftlen, left);

        else if (n > (arrsize - rightlen)) {
            n = n - (leftlen);
            return partition(n, rightlen, right);
        }

        else return pivot;

}
```

Comment: Is this an exercise, or would using [`std::nth_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/nth_element) be acceptable?

Comment: @juanchopanza I'm doing some exercises from Careercup website. I know how to use the `nth_element` function but I'd like to know the long version too

Comment: `if (n < leftlen)` should probably be using `<=`, unless your input has a 0-th largest element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are creating new vectors anyway (I suppose because you don't want to mutate the input vector), you might as well just avoid putting the pivot element into either left or right. In that case, if the pivot turns out to be the element you're looking for, it will be caught by `else return pivot`, and if you end up with the degenerate case where the partition is all equal elements, then nothing will be placed into either left or right, and the single value of the partition will be correctly returned.

The way quicksort avoids this problem is to never put the pivot element into the subvectors which are being sorted; consequently, even if one of the vectors ends up being all the same element, it still ends up being shorter than it was. That's a subtlety with quicksort which is rarely explained well, although Sedgwick does discuss ways to improve quicksort's performance on vectors with many repeated elements.

Comment: Ah even better I've made the changes to my code and it all works great now using a number of different values for n and N. Thanks for clearing that up for me

Answer (score 1):

Checking for either of sub-arrays being empty will help to detect infinite loop, and also a crash in some other cases.

```
int leftlen = left.size();
int rightlen = right.size();
if (leftlen == 0 || rightlen == 0) /* break processing */
```

**Edit** An infinite loop is only possible when either of the arrays is 0 and the other one is filled with the same value.

Comment: I have seen it work in some runs with some empty arrays though so this is not necessarily the correct solution. On one run there I had the right array be empty in one iteration but then had an element in the next iteration

Comment: Makes sense. Then an infinite loop is only happening when either of arrays is filled with the same number. Check for that, and you still need to make sure not to pass an empty vector to partition().

Comment: Ah that's it check if each array element is the same. I surprise myself with my stupidity sometimes! Thanks

Comment: Look at @rici 's solution -- it is more efficient not to store the pivot in vectors at all.